# Able to Run on GenyMotion (Sumsung Note 3) But not others?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

its my first post... pardon me any cause.

So It just force closed on the "intro" page, however it can run very smoothly on my personal phone and only Samsung Note 3 virtual Devices.

Having error code on - Samsung S5 phone:

**Errors log which is displaying on "Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6:"**
&
**Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cuzor.master.master/com.cuzor.master.master.intro}:**

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cuzor.master.master/com.cuzor.master.master.intro}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at com.cuzor.master.master.intro.onCreate(intro.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

My Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.cuzor.master.select");
                startActivity(menuIntent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                finish();

            }
        }

    };
    logoTimer.start();
} }
```

Manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">


    <activity
        android:name=".MAIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".intro"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.intro" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".select"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.select" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".zero"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.zero" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ten"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.ten" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".twenty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.twenty" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".thirty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.thirty" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".forty"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.forty" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".fifty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.fifty" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".sixty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.sixty" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".seventy"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.seventy" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".eighty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.eighty" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ninety"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.ninety" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".hundred"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cuzor.master.hundred" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: I found out my own problem was my Image was way too big for the phone... Out of Memory, So i reduce my Imagine Size from 1080x1920 to only 600x1024 ! For more information go to : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

And it WORKED for all the phone devices ! YEYEE..